# change a flash to jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, flash

have a flash embeded in my website where I need to change to jquery, There wo issues i am struggling with:
this flash is done for loading images, the point is that these images are got through xml,in other words there is a function created that searches for the images, the results got are stores in xml file and then in a certain way are sent in webservlink as flash variables.

The point is that I greated  a jquery to load these images but the point , how I have to get the images from the xml and put them in the list I created

Comment: You mean, how do I read XML using javascript? Look into jQuery.parseXML

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the XML format, you could use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function()   
     {   
       $.get('/images.xml', function(data){    

       $(data).find('img').each(function(){    
           var image = $(this);    
           var img_src = $book.attr("src");   

            (new Image()).src = image;   
        });   
    });   
});
```